# my session_id changes, and the session does not save the data

Tags: php, session, codeigniter

here are the parts that i think are relevant:

EDIT: when i use regular `$_SESSION` - evrything works...

function A saves the session data, than calls a view, that returns the data the user added to it to function B.
both function A and function B are on the same controller.
im using 2.0.2 version.. so when it also asked me to enter encryption key in the config file.

the problem is, that the session don't save the data when i move between the pages..
i also noticed that it changes the session_id varible...

do you know what am i doing wrong?

another important information - i return a value threw the URL to function B.

controller welcome: functionA

```
                    ...
        $data = array(
            'username' => $myusername,
            'is_logged_in' => true,
            'permissions' =>$permissions
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
                    ...
                    ...
                    $this->load->view('login_success',$dataV);
```

controller welcome: functionB

```
          $user=$this->session->userdata('username');       
          echo "<br> IN LINK REFERENCE: $user";
```

do you know what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but looks like you haven't initialized your `Session` library. Can you please check if you have initialized `Session` library correctly? Please check `$autoload['libraries'] = array();` in `config/autoload` directory.

Comment: i loaded the library in the controllers constructor:
$this->load->library('session');

Comment: did you load it in both controller?

Comment: and now i added the 'session' to the autoload in config, but the session_id still changes..

Comment: `session_id` change isn't an issue. Can you please check if you are accessing both function is correct order?

Comment: Sorry... the question is wrong. Can you please check that you have set the `encryption_key` in `config`? You just need to set that, it will be used as security salt. Its in `applicaiton/config/config.php`, line `$config['encryption_key']`. Then it will work as your expectation.

Comment: as i said, i edited to encryption_key - added something.. cause without it, nothing would work. 

it still doesnt work. now im using php regular _SESSION, and it works with that, but i want it to work with codeignitor session helper.

Comment: I have just tried by setting `encryption_key` and it is working fine for me. Here is my code in `Welcome` controller. `class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

 public function  __construct() {
  parent::__construct();
  $this->load->library('session');
 }

 public function index()
 {

  $data = array(
   'user_name' => "Stack",
   'TEST' => 'success'
  );
  $this->session->set_userdata($data);
  
 $this->load->view('welcome_message');
 }

 public function test(){
  var_dump($this->session->userdata('user_name'));
 }

}`